# HTC One M7 Keeps Restarting Itself

Tags: hardware, boot-loop, htc-one-x

I have recently bought a new HTC One M7.
Since the moment I turned it on it's performing random reboots. At the begining it was every few minutes but now its every time I unlock the screen.
I've performed 3 factory resets - didn't help (I think that even made it worse)
I've entered "safe mode" - still rebooting
I've tried to enter recovery mode but the phone got stuck on the loading screen (exclamation point icon)

Anyone might have an idea what's going on?
Is the phone defective? Might it be a hardware issue?

As I said, the phone is new, so no custom ROMs or strange apps installed

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a hardware issue or ROM corruption. One solution would be to try re-installing the ROM, or even change the ROM.

Comment: doesn't a factory reset re-installs the ROM?

Comment: I think it only wipes the internal user data

Comment: So how do I re-install the ROM? where can I find a tutorial and image for a stable ROM? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

At the end the problem was with the internal thermostat.
Had to replace the device.

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, still rebooting in safe mode. I found Amazon's software was using up approx. 55% of the CPU, and was kicking my computer off of the internet. Disabled Amazon, uninstalled all updates, and disabled automatic updates, and now phone is back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

what you have to do is hold the up volume button and press the power button once. once you do that you will see a set of commands and once you do that you will want to select the wipe cache partition and once you do that it will just clean out the battery and it should allow it to work from there.

Comment: While "wipe cache" is in fact not a bad suggestion, I've never heard that "will just clean out the battery", Jaime. Are you confusing something here? ;) // You describe [booting into recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info). I've just added the link to details on that, as the process might be different on different devices.